# Extending recursively defined interface member

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type defined in a library (`TreeItem`) and I want to extend this type with an optional `onClick` function (`TreeItem2`).

How do I extend the type without copying the whole declaration?

This is my code so far:

```js
// type defined in library
interface TreeItem {
    text?: string;
    items?: TreeItem[];
    // ...
};

// extended type
type TreeItem2 = TreeItem & { items?: TreeItem2[], onClick?: () => void };

// type usage
let item: TreeItem2 = {
    text: "a",
    onClick: () => {},
    items: [{
        text: "b",
        onClick: () => {}, // error
    }]
};
```

Error message:

```
Type '{ text: string; onClick: () => void; }[]' is not assignable to type 'TreeItem[] & TreeItem2[]'.
  Type '{ text: string; onClick: () => void; }[]' is not assignable to type 'TreeItem[]'.
    Type '{ text: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'TreeItem'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'onClick' does not exist in type 'TreeItem'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2sGg6ANqgEYBOAhsZAFAbizHKkDG8AKsbLAJK0C2oA3pVDCIsAB7gA-AC5QAZ3DEMAcwDcQkal5yZoNh26weAbQC66kaBCgAdHcoBfdZWvja6JNihxK31uy5eACZQAF49AMM+ADIBHG1dfUCjILMAGlAAe3QAYQJGAGtdAAoASjCAPlAAN0zUbCdKFzA-UABXOVJlWEo8WHB4o1kkqJDwwUtaCVkAIlIZtI1hbLzUQtkyyoEHRcstIzlZYwnLESnwWcIFpdOV-IKN8tCq-h2rMDpiTOIbh1NHVRAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using polymorphic `this` would have been the easiest way to achieve this, but it requires editing the base type, which we can't do since it's in a library. Still for completeness this would be the version:

```
interface TreeItem {
    text?: string;
    items?: this[];
};

interface TreeItem2 extends TreeItem {
    onClick: ()=> void
}

let item: TreeItem2 = {
    text: "a",
    onClick: () => {},
    items: [{
        text: "b",
        onClick: () => {}, // ok 
    }]
};
```

Since we can't edit the library type, we can instead omit `items` from the original interface and define a custom interface containing an updated `items` property:

```
// type defined in library
interface TreeItem {
    text?: string;
    items?: TreeItem[];
};

interface TreeItem2 extends Omit<TreeItem, 'items'> {
    onClick: ()=> void
    items?: TreeItem2[]
}

let item: TreeItem2 = {
    text: "a",
    onClick: () => {},
    items: [{
        text: "b",
        onClick: () => {}, // ok 
    }]
};
```